Can I apply for a Schengen visa from India if I am an Indian national studying in USA?
I am an Indian national studying in the USA and visiting my family in India for the summer break. I wish to travel to Switzerland with my family and plan to apply with them while I am there. Recently discovered that I will need to justify lodging the application from a place where I am a non resident. Wondering if someone here has faced similar situation and have been able to successfully get the visa. If so could you share what could be an acceptable reason to be considered in this case?

The Common Information Sheet for India (eg: https://consmumbai.esteri.it/en/servizi-consolari-e-visti/servizi-per-il-cittadino-straniero/common-information-sheet-for-schengen-visa-applicants-in-india/) clearly state that "Indian nationals and nationals of other countries legally residing in India can apply." so you should be fine? I know that in the next line it says that "Persons who do not reside in India may only apply if they are legally present in India and can present a justification for lodging an application in India rather than in ..." but my guess is that it's only for non-Indians.

Yes I did see that earlier, but reached out to VFS to clarify and ask which address I should fill out in my application form. Their response was "you should be residing for past 6 months in India to apply from India". I reached out to the Swiss consulate via email and this is the response I got:

"Please be informed that as it is said in the Regulation of the European Parliament and the Council on behalf of the Visa Code Art. 6.1: An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.
Since you have been residing in the USA, you must contact the competent Swiss representation there, responsible for your residence, for any further assistance. We are not competent to treat this request due to territorial competencies."

I also reached out to the Swiss Embassy in USA and they replied with "Generally you are required to apply at the responsible consulate you reside. If you wish to apply in India, please contact the consulate directly to see if they may make an exception and accommodate your request."

So I really want to know - Should I call this out in my application in India and how to best explain this.

This question is similar to: Can I apply for Schengen Visa from a country where I'm not resident but a citizen?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note that Leaderboards misinterpretation of the text he is quoting is already discussed in the question I am linking to.
